# Почему htaccess не работает на localhost mmap?

Tags: nginx, .htaccess, apache

Перенес сайт с хостинга на локалхост, но переходя по ссылке пишет: 404 Not Found
nginx/1.19.2

В htaccess я прописал чтобы ссылка вида site.ru/company/1/profile работала
Т.е чтобы вместо цифры 1 было айди компании и открывалась соответствующая компания

```
AddDefaultCharset utf-8

Options +FollowSymLinks
Options -Indexes
DirectoryIndex index.php

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %\{HTTP_HOST\} ^localhost$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ localhost/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^company/([0-9]+)/?$ company/index.php?id=$1&%\{QUERY_STRING\} [NS,L]

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\\.php)\
RewriteCond %\{REQUEST_URI\} !^.*\\.(jpg|css|js|gif|png)$ [NC]\
RewriteCond %\{REQUEST_FILENAME\} !-f\
RewriteCond %\{REQUEST_FILENAME\} !-d\

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /404.php?$1 [L,QSA]\

php_value session.gc_maxlifetime 86400\
php_value session.cookie_lifetime 86400\

php_flag display_errors off\
php_value error_reporting 0}
```

Comment: `404 Not Found nginx/1.19.2` не смушает ошибка nginx? причем тут htaccess...

Comment: а что там еще может быть не так? все тоже самое как было до этого

Comment: nginx конфиг не корректный... и .htaccess работает только с  apache, непонятно чем вы там занимаетесь, обновите вопрос.

Comment: Определитесь, что у вас там: nginx, apache. И не ставтье теги javascript, html и php - они не имеют никакого отношения к теме вопроса.